# How to get single sheet from multisheet workbook in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I have shared a google workbook and I have created a key and so I can retrieve the structure of the workbook with the following link

[Google Sheets - Copy of Guardian University Guide 2018](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nDSd38lIQj_aTWDRPJ-aPybR0NwFdQ8GLSDJM0-QaR4?key=AIzaSyBUHA34c7FmNLut1V7Pe3lIJTk3pX39J6E)

and in the results I can see the sheets in an array, so first element in an array has sheetId of 1544561606 so I presume somehow I can form a second url with this sheetId as well as original spreadsheet id and get the contents of the this sheet but the documentation is sparse IMHO.  THen I can do the same for all the other sheets.  I just can't find the correct url format.  Please help.

This is version 4.0 of Google Sheets API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your endpoint, the sheet name of the sheet ID `1544561606` is "Institutional". You can retrieve the sheet data using this sheet name. The endpoint is as follows.

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1nDSd38lIQj_aTWDRPJ-aPybR0NwFdQ8GLSDJM0-QaR4/values/Institutional?key=AIzaSyBUHA34c7FmNLut1V7Pe3lIJTk3pX39J6E

#### Reference :

- [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @S Meaden Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.